# How can I render product category and it's subcategory list alphabetically sorted in Django-Oscar?

Tags: woocommerce, django-oscar

I can render the product category list in template. But the category list are not showing in alphabetical order. How can I render them in alphabetical order ?

**Edit**

I am using the following code to render categories and subcategories.

```
<ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
                {% for tree_category, info in tree_categories %}
                    <li {% if info.has_children %}class="has-children"
                        {% else %}{% endif %}>

                        {% if info.has_children %}

                            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ tree_category.name|lower }}"
                                   id="{{ tree_category.name|lower }}">
                            <label for="{{ tree_category.name|lower }}">{{ tree_category.name|safe }}
                        {% else %}
                            <a href="{{ tree_category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tree_category.name|safe }}</a>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if info.has_children %}</label>{% endif %}

                        {% if info.has_children %}
                            <ul>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% for n in info.num_to_close %}
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

**This shows the categories as below.**
[image]

Comment: – LoicTheAztec 
Edited.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement, and ended up customising the category_tree template tag. I copied the original implementation of category_tree (see [link](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/templatetags/category_tags.py)) and added a sorting step to sort. Only one lined changed in comparison to the original category_tree template tag.

```
from django import template

from oscar.core.loading import get_model

register = template.Library()
Category = get_model('catalogue', 'category')


@register.assignment_tag(name="category_tree")
def get_annotated_list(depth=None, parent=None):
    """
    Gets an annotated list from a tree branch.
    Borrows heavily from treebeard's get_annotated_list
    """
    # 'depth' is the backwards-compatible name for the template tag,
    # 'max_depth' is the better variable name.

    max_depth = depth

    annotated_categories = []

    start_depth, prev_depth = (None, None)
    if parent:
        categories = parent.get_descendants()
        if max_depth is not None:
            max_depth += parent.get_depth()
    else:
        categories = Category.get_tree()

    info = {}
    # CUSTOM SORTING HERE 
    for node in sorted(categories, key=lambda x: x.name):

        node_depth = node.get_depth()
        if start_depth is None:
            start_depth = node_depth
        if max_depth is not None and node_depth > max_depth:
            continue

        # Update previous node's info
        info['has_children'] = prev_depth is None or node_depth > prev_depth
        if prev_depth is not None and node_depth < prev_depth:
            info['num_to_close'] = list(range(0, prev_depth - node_depth))

        info = {'num_to_close': [],
                'level': node_depth - start_depth}
        annotated_categories.append((node, info,))
        prev_depth = node_depth

    if prev_depth is not None:
        # close last leaf
        info['num_to_close'] = list(range(0, prev_depth - start_depth))
        info['has_children'] = prev_depth > prev_depth

    return annotated_categories
```

PS: check the django docs if you don't know how to include custom templatetags, they need to go in a dedicated folder.

Template code:

```
<ul class="cd-accordion-menu animated">
  {% for tree_category, info in tree_categories %}
      <li {% if info.has_children %}class="has-children"
          {% else %}{% endif %}>

          {% if info.has_children %}
              <input type="checkbox" name="{{ tree_category.name|lower }}" id="{{ tree_category.name|lower }}">
              <label for="{{ tree_category.name|lower }}">{{ tree_category.name|safe }}</label>
          {% else %}
              <a href="{{ tree_category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tree_category.name|safe }}</a>
          {% endif %}

          {% if info.has_children %}
              <ul>
          {% else %}
              </li>
          {% endif %}

          {% for n in info.num_to_close %}
              </ul>
              </li>
          {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this does not solved my issues.

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Comment: It's showing like this **https://ibb.co/b4FDsH**. Will you please look at the above code I am using for rendering in the template ?

Comment: Okay, just one question: how many levels deep is your category tree? Only categories and subcategories, or do you go even deeper?

Comment: I edited my answer, but that template code is just out of my head, I did not test it ...

Answer (score 0):

Just try to order the ***MP_Node***.

```
class Category(AbstractCategory):

    node_order_by = ['name']
```